# Stop Desktops from Reordering

Tags: desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do full-screen applications change their order in Mission Control?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24836/why-do-full-screen-applications-change-their-order-in-mission-control)

Say I'm on desktop 1 and a click an app in the dock for a window on desktop 3.  It will reorder my desktops, moving 3 to 2.  How can I keep it from doing this?

Answer (score 9):

The setting to turn that off is in your Mission Control preference pane.

[image: image of setting]