# Full-screen apps and desktop arrangements

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mission-control, fullscreen

[image]

The picture above is a screenshot from Mission Control showing the desktop and full-screen apps. The problem is that I want a different arrangement. I want the order to be Safari-Desktop-iTunes. I can't drag the desktop between Safari and iTunes apps, and when I drag Safari to the left of the Desktop, it goes back to its original place. So how can I modify the place of the Desktop? (I want to use only one Desktop, I know that it is possible when other Desktops are added) By the way I'm using Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, mission control is set up in such a way that the dashboard and the first desktop are immutable (i.e. cannot be changed). There might be a flag or something for it somewhere that you could disable that behaviour, but it would definitely require some serious digging since it's part of how mission control is written.

Comment: Then any recommendation about where to search?

Comment: [This](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25085/how-do-i-change-the-desktop-order-in-mission-control) has a tip to prevent automatic reordering but I haven't found anything so far that would let you put apps to the left of the first desktop. Maybe you could open up a second desktop and, disabling automatic reordering, you could do desktop 1 - Safari - desktop 2 - iTunes?

Comment: I've already done this and I would prefer to have only one desktop but nevertheless, thanks for your answer...