# prevent desktops/fullscreen windows from being re-ordered

Tags: mission-control, desktop

When an application gains focus, it can change the order of desktops in mission control.  In my mind, this creates some very confusion animations.

Can we force desktops to stay in their order?
Can we disable the animation entirely? (I saw the thread here, nothing seemed to wrok.)

Comment: Which thread did you see? Links help.

Comment: Which does answer not work for you exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Please, look [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17985/is-it-possible-to-reorder-spaces-in-lion) and [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17929/how-can-i-disable-animation-when-switching-desktops-in-lion) QAs which have answers for your questions.